# How can I find a complete deleted script in google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This morning I open my script and everything has disappeared. Nothing in my sheet history either!

Is there something to help me or should I rewrite everything ?

Comment: Looks that there are other people having the same issue (Official Google Drive / Docs Help Forum in Spanish): https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=es#!topic/docs-es/kZtAoHN56c8 .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with some spreadsheets in our company (but not all). This seems to be an issue on Google's side. Apparently, the link between the spreadsheet and the script file is broken (Google cites a cache related issue), so the custom Spreadsheet menus and using "Tools > Script Editor" doesn't work.

The scripts, however, are not lost, since any trigger you might have set is still running. Some users report that the scripts do appear after a few hours, so keep checking yours.

If you need the script right now, you should rewrite it. If it's not urgent, just wait for Google to fix the problem and your scripts should come back safely.

For more details check this issue in the Google Apps Script issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5923&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner